# Accelerating speed of reading contents from dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

Let us suppose we have table with following dimension :

```
print(metadata.shape)-(8732, 8)
```

[image]

let us suppose we want to read slice_file_name  for each row( and then read   sound files from drive ) and  extract  mel frequencies :

```
def feature_extractor(file_name):
  audio,sample_rate =librosa.load(file_name,res_type='kaiser_fast')
  mfccs_features =librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio,sr=sample_rate,n_mfcc=40)
  mfccs_scaled_features =np.mean(mfccs_features.T,axis=0)
  return mfccs_scaled_features
```

if i use following loops :

```
from tqdm import tqdm
extracted_features =[]
for index_num, row in  tqdm(metadata.iterrows()):
    file_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(Base_Directory),str(row["slice_file_name"]))
    final_class_labels=row["class"]
    data=feature_extractor(file_name)
    extracted_features.append([data,final_class_labels])
```

it takes in total following amount of time :

```
3555it [21:15,  2.79it/s]/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.py:224: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=1323
  n_fft, y.shape[-1]
8326it [48:40,  3.47it/s]/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.py:224: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=1103
  n_fft, y.shape[-1]
8329it [48:41,  3.89it/s]/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.py:224: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=1523
  n_fft, y.shape[-1]
8732it [50:53,  2.86it/s]
```

how can i  optimize this code to  do the thing in less amount of time? it is possible?

Comment: You could try parallelizing feature_extractor, either with a thread or process pool.

Comment: Approximately  by how much percentage  will be  running time  minimized?

Comment: Given 4 cores, approximately 4x faster.

Comment: unfortunately google colab  give only  1 worker,i dont want to run this code in  leptop(not good for fan)

Comment: My code with `apply` instead of `parallel_apply` will work just fine, and probably run a bit faster due to only getting the `PATH` once, and not making a custom, less efficient, loop.

Comment: thanks for  help, i hope it takes faster then 50 minute(which is enough for child born :D :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and run the feature extractor in parallel, this could give a new column in your dataframe with the `mfccs_scaled_features`.

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

PATH = os.path.abspath(Base_Directory)

def feature_extractor(file_name):
    # If using windows, you may need to put these here~
    # import librosa 
    # import numpy as np
    # import os
    
    file_name = os.path.join(PATH, file_name)
    audio,sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
    mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
    mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T, axis=0)
    return mfccs_scaled_features

df['mfccs_scaled_features'] = df['slice_file_name'].parallel_apply(feature_extractor)
```

Comment: what about class label?

Comment: Class label is still part of your DataFrame... do with it whatever you want.

Comment: so you mean that  i should  add  column to the existing  dataframe and then extract both of them?

Comment: Yes, working within a dataframe structure instead of making your own loops will be faster. If you need a list formatted `[[mfccs_scaled_features, class],...]` then `df[['mfccs_scaled_features', 'class']].to_dict('records')` will give you something fairly close.

Comment: now i am checking  to see what will be total amount of running time

Comment: If you're using a jupyter notebook or something, you can initialize with `pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)` for progress bars.